# Active filter has unintended attenuation for lower frequencies

Tags: transfer-function, low-pass, active-filter, attenuation

I have design an active filter with an online tool. The circuit looks as follows: 
[image]

It should be a low pass filter of 3rd order with a cut-off frequency at 50kHz.

Unfortunately, it attenuatues DC components and some lower frequencies as well as seen in the transfer function below:

[image]

In case of DC input, the whole voltage drops at the potential shown below as a red dot.

[image]

I cannot explain this behaviour. Does anyone know what might cause such a behaviour?

Thanks.

PS: For the measurement setup I used a signal generator for the input signal and I measured the transfer function with a Sampled ACV measurement function of the DMM HP3458.

Comment: I guess the 2nd order filter is not correct. Give some links, references where you have found it.

Comment: I designed it using the design tool from analog devices: 
https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/

The simulations with LTSpice went well and didn't show any signs of attenuations at lower frequencies.

Comment: Split your problem into smaller parts. I'd measure at the output of the left opamp, what transfer do you get? If it is still not flat at lower freqs. then the problem is on the left of the circuit. If the response is flat then the right side is the issue. The circuit you show should not have the shown behavior so maybe something outside that circuit is causing the issue. What supply voltages are you using? Is there supply decoupling present?

Comment: Stupid questions - how are you measuring the frequency response with an HP3458A which is a high precision metrology grade DVM that, according to the data sheet, does not contain a signal generator and in one AC measurement mode appears to roll off at low frequencies.? What test setup are you using? Are these real physical measurements on a circuit you actually built, or are they some sort of simulation?

Comment: I am using a signal generator to generate a sine function with different frequencies and I use an implemented function of the HP3458A. To explain it briefly, that function uses an algorithm to calculate the AC value of a signal by sampling it. And yes, the filter is on a print and I connect the DMM and the signal generator with it.

Comment: What is your power supply config? You need a split supply. Either that or create a virtual ground at your single supply midpoint. Without this your physical circuit won't work properly.

Comment: Is the graph measured or simulated ?

Comment: All assumptions must be verified!! Vdc input, Vcc,Vee, Vout is inside CM range , linear range. And Vdc diff. Input ~ zero. Sloppy specs= poor design verification test DVT

Comment: @Soldersmoke What do you mean by split supply? I have a DC supply for my OPV and as a test signal I use the signal generator. Is this what you mean by split supply? 
Where is the single supply midpoint?

Comment: @Hilmar The graph is measured with the DMM.

Comment: I'd measure with a less-fancy instrument, or an oscilloscope. If you're AC sampling synchronously, you may be catching a sampling alias in that 100-1000 Hz region.

Comment: Seriously? Well, split supply means power supply which has a +ve and a -ve and Ground in between

Comment: Theer's something else going on, nothing to do with the filter as described. Test the sig gen directly into the DMM for a start, or find an oscilloscope.

Comment: " What do you mean by split supply?" Oh boy. There's your problem, or at least your first problem. You need two supplies, call them A and B. Let's say that both of them are 5 volts. Connect the - of A to ground, and the + of B to ground. Now connect A+ to the V+ of the 823, and B- to V-. With your meter referenced to ground, you should read +5 on V+ and -5 on V-. An op amp cannot drive an output voltage higher than its + supply or lower than its - supply, so you can't expect a usable result with a single supply,. The only puzzle is why it works at all at higher frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your DMM HP3458 setup is incorrect for a low frequency signal.  Perhaps the number of readings is sufficient if using the 100ksps rate in order to capture the entire wave.
2. Your filter is a bit weird.
   R1A * C2A = 50 kHz ok
   R1B * C1B = 13 kHz
   R2B * C2B =  4 MHz

Update :
The Red Dot is supposed to be null DC as the non-inverting input is reference is 0V this means the DC gain is unity by virtue of R18=R58. So the conclusion is measurement setup error, again.

Comment: The 3458 AC function is good down to 1 Hz. Or at least that's what the data sheet says.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of an operational amplifier is to keep 0V between inverting and non-inverting inputs. As there is 0V on non-inverting input, the voltage at red dot will be kept 0V as per the feedback.

Comment: I think his only applies for DC. For AC, the red dot can theoretically be anything. The red dot node =/= inverting input node of the opamp. The inverting input of the opamp will be kept 0V as per the feedback.

Comment: The red dot is not directly connected to ground or the any of the op amp inputs. I don't understand your argument.

Comment: This is not "the whole point of an operational amplifier". The virtual short between inverting and non-inverting inputs is only seen with **negative feedback**, it is not inherent in all operational amplifier circuits.

Comment: Whenever making a frequency response of a circuit, you should feed one frequency to see if the circuit is clipping. Your circuit has no "virtual ground" so it is rectifying the signal.